# Initialize variables with ".()" expression in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, initialization, higher-order-functions, ktor

I'm using Ktor to make websocket requests.
The method "websocket(...)" I use takes two lambda expressions.

[image]

So as I only can call one with curly brackets I have to give the other one via a variable. So I tried this:

```kotlin
val request: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit
val socket = ktorHttpClient.webSocket(request = request) {

}
```

The data types fit now but of course it still says "Variable 'request' must be initialized", so I tried to initialize it:

```kotlin
val request: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = HttpRequestBuilder.()
```

Now the error is gone but inside the last brackets it says "Expecting an expression", what am I missing here?

PS: Maybe there's even somebody who can explain in detail how initialization works when using ".()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, you need to pass two lambdas. You can do it either directly:

```kotlin
ktorHttpClient.webSocket({ /* request lambda */ }) {
    /* block lambda */
}
```

Or split it as you did:

```kotlin
val request: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = { /* request lambda */ } 
val socket = ktorHttpClient.webSocket(request) {
    /* block lambda */
}
```

More info on how to initialize lambdas / function types can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type

Comment: Wow, another pair of curly brackets actually work, I just did not think about adding the "request =..." .
But now I know how to initialize the high-order function in a variable, thanks a lot!

Comment: See updated answer. I added a link to official docs about lambdas in Kotlin. There are more ways to pass a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Just use named parameters with lambdas:

```
ktorHttpClient.webSocket(request = {}, block = {})
```